# Отображение списка в dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Вот заполнение таблицы из бд:

```
public Catalog(DbSet<T> set, BusDepotContext db)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        set.Load();
        dataGridView.DataSource = set.Local.ToBindingList();
    }
```

Однако, список (Drivers, который представлен ICollection = new List()) он отобразить не может:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно подобное реализовать? Спасибо.

Comment: `set.Load();` - вы загрузили родительские сущности. Также нужно загрузить дочерние Drivers.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а можно поподробнее, как это сделать?